# The content in form window is not selectable. It also drag the whole inner content when try to select. how to avoid it

Tags: forms, extjs

```
var settingForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    frame: false,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    forceSelection: true,
    fieldDefaults: {
        labelAlign: 'right',
        //msgTarget: 'side',
        labelWidth: 140
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        anchor: '100%',
        title: 'Some Information',
        layout: 'column',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            columnWidth: .5,
            layout: 'anchor',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                name: 'txtHiddenId',
                id: 'txtHiddenId'
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Host Name',
                name: 'txtHostName',
                id: 'txtHostNameId',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '96%',
                disabled: true,
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keypress: function() {
                        manageUpdate();
                    },
                    specialkey: function(field, e) {
                        if (e.getKey() == "46" || e.getKey() == "8")
                            manageUpdate();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Formatting in your example is gone...Anyway did you check z-order?

Comment: yes, i have given z-index: 20000;

Comment: i was try to edit by ctrl+k, but it gives me error. I have made the question log because I need it to be more explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove  `draggable: true` and `forceSelection: true`. See if it helps.

Comment: How is this panel rendered? Do you include it in the Window or what's exactly is happening outside the panel class?